# Bringing data from sql server - existing data not brought

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that brings data from sql server. The function is tested and is used in many macros. Now I am trying to use it and for some reason it doesn't work, although I am testing the query and it does have data

I opened a macro where the function works and try to test it from there, but still doesn't work.

I am calling to function GetDataFromDatabase (see below) from the following code:

```
Sub testing()
    Dim query As String
    Dim ImportedData As Range

    query = GetQuery
    Debug.Print query
    Call GetDataFromDatabase(query, Range("AB1"), False)
End Sub
```

Note, that when debug.pring prints the query, I take it, run in in the database and I get the data, so the GetQuery function works.

The function includes the following line:

```
On Error GoTo CloseConnection
```

And indeed, at some point it goes to closeConnection (line marked below in the function). How do I know what is the error?

```
Sub GetDataFromDatabase(query As String, cellToCpyData As Range, WithHeaders As Boolean)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim LocalDBCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim SqlTableDatasSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SqlDataSetFields As ADODB.Field
Dim Ctr As Long
Dim RDBConString As String


RDBConString = "connection string (the right one)"' This here is ok, I deleted the actual sting


Set LocalDBCon = New ADODB.Connection
Set SqlTableDatasSet = New ADODB.Recordset
LocalDBCon.ConnectionString = RDBConString

On Error GoTo CloseConnection
LocalDBCon.Open

    With SqlTableDatasSet
        .ActiveConnection = LocalDBCon
        .ActiveConnection.CommandTimeout = 0
        .Source = query
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    'Adding the sql table headers
    If WithHeaders Then
        Ctr = 0
        For Each SqlDataSetFields In SqlTableDatasSet.Fields
            cellToCpyData.Offset(0, Ctr) = SqlDataSetFields.Name
            Ctr = Ctr + 1
        Next SqlDataSetFields
        Set cellToCpyData = cellToCpyData.Offset(1, 0)
    End If


 ---->>cellToCpyData.CopyFromRecordset SqlTableDatasSet 'When not working, jumps from here to CloseConnection<<------------------------------------
        SqlTableDatasSet.Close


Wrapup:
    On Error Resume Next
    LocalDBCon.Close
    Exit Sub

CloseConnection:
    On Error Resume Next
    LocalDBCon.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line of code between "CloseConnection:" and "On Error Resume Next"

```
Debug.Print Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
```

This will print to the immediate window what error is causing the problem. That will give a starting point to go from.

Comment: Thanks @Kiran, So I did it and the error is: 3704 - operation is not allowed when the object is closed. Searching for this error I see that it has to do with the insert statement in SQL (and indeed my query includes insert statement). I still didn't figure out what is the problem. The weird thing is that when I manually run the query, all works fine

Comment: Try adding SET NOCOUNT ON as the first line your SQL query. You don't have to do it with scripts that don't do INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations (i.e. scripts that just have a SELECT statement).